# Kivy & KivyMD App Crashes on Launch Android

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

when I compile my kivy & kivymd app for android using buildozer, the APK is created just fine but when I open it on my android phone it shows the splash screen then crashes. I have read online that this issue usually occurs because a package that is used in the python code is not added into `requirements =`  in the buildozer.spec file. This appears to not be the problem in my case and I have no idea what to do as online forums have not helped. All comments are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Main.py imports**:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import numpy as np
from statistics import mean
import math
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot, SmoothLinePlot
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import os
```

**Main.kv imports**:

```
#:import partial functools.partial
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory
```

**Buildozer.spec requirements:**

```
requirements = python3,kivy, kivymd, numpy, statistic
```

**Full buildozer.spec file**

https://pastebin.com/fFHZNGzE

Comment: can you provide logcat? logcat will provide all the details why your app is crashing (most probably a missing dependency that one of your requirement depends upon or whatever be the reason). You can check here how to get logcat: https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/#debugging-on-android

Comment: did you found any solutions

Comment: I am having similar problem